# Since, volume and pressure are inversely proportional to each other, shouldn't volume decrease whenever pressure is increased?

Tags: thermodynamics

How can pressure be increased without decreasing volume?

Comment: Think about what's on "the other side" of the relation.

Comment: Read more on Boyle's law, which is the law that states the inverse relationship. But only for a constant temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the pressure by increasing the temperature -  [Pressure-temperature law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay%E2%80%93Lussac_law#Pressure-temperature_law), also known as Amontons' Law of Pressure-Temperature. The basic idea is in the diagram below:

[image]

The law states that:

> The pressure of a gas of fixed mass and fixed volume is directly proportional to the gas's absolute temperature.

As the temperature increases, so does the average kinetic energy of the particles, resulting in more collisions with the fixed container wall, thus exerting a greater pressure on the container.

There is also the [isochoric process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochoric_process) - from the Wikipedia page:

> An isochoric process, also called a constant-volume process, an isovolumetric process, or an isometric process, is a thermodynamic process during which the volume of the closed system undergoing such a process remains constant. An isochoric process is exemplified by the heating or the cooling of the contents of a sealed, inelastic container: The thermodynamic process is the addition or removal of heat; the isolation of the contents of the container establishes the closed system; and the inability of the container to deform imposes the constant-volume condition. The isochoric process here should be a quasi-static process.

Essentially, with $V$ constant, $P$ is proportional to $T$

Comment: I assume in Amonton's law matter is conserved?  The diagram seems to suggest that new molecules have sprung into existence?

Answer (score 0):

Volume is only inversely proportional to pressure if the amount of gas and temperature remains constant. Let's say you squeeze a balloon, you are decreasing the volume and increasing the pressure. In this case, pressure and volume are inversely proportional.

If you just heat the surroundings, you will find that the pressure increases, the volume would also increase as well.

It really depends on the scenario, whether other factor are constant or not. Hope that helps :D